# Swift: Why class method has return type AnyObject?

Tags: swift, initialization, nsdate, return-type, class-method

`NSDate.distantFuture()` is documented to return an object of type `NSDate`.

So then, why does it have a return type of `AnyObject`, instead of `NSDate`?

Comment: I really doubt they've converted frameworks manually, might be an explanation.

Answer (score 7):

In Objective-C `distantFuture` returns an `id`, not `NSDate`. Automatic Swift conversion makes this an `AnyObject`. When the class will be reviewed by Apple they will probably switch that to `NSDate`.

NSDate's `distantFuture` is actually from the distant past (at least Mac OS X 10.0, probably even before that). At this time many factory methods returned `id` because there was no `instancetype`. It was just to make it easier to call a subclasses method on the returned object.

Comment: Haha. OK. Thanks! So, when writing a factory method for my own custom class, I should just return the specific type, e.g., `NSDate`, and not `AnyObject`, if I know that type will be returned every time? Sorry, but that's actually the real question I was getting at. I just asked it about Apple's code because I usually model my code after theirs.

Answer (score -1):

**This is actually documented as returning AnyObject.**

**returns nil if an event specified in the event mask does not happen before the specified date.**

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDate/distantFuture**

distantFuture
Creates and returns an NSDate object representing a date in the distant future.

Declaration
SWIFT
class func distantFuture() -> AnyObject
OBJECTIVE-C
+ (id)distantFuture
Return Value
An NSDate object representing a date in the distant future (in terms of centuries).

Discussion
You can pass this value when an NSDate object is required to have the date argument essentially ignored. For example, the NSWindow method nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue: returns nil if an event specified in the event mask does not happen before the specified date. You can use the object returned by distantFuture as the date argument to wait indefinitely for the event to occur.

myEvent = [myWindow nextEventMatchingMask:myEventMask
    untilDate:[NSDate distantFuture]
    inMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode
    dequeue:YES];
Import Statement
import Foundation

Availability
Available in OS X v10.0 and later.

Comment: You are confusing return type and return value.

Comment: No he isn't, it's just a dump from the documentation. If you look at this documentation (pre release) it is typed as NSDate https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDate/distantFuture